# SQL - Pivot table - uneven rows per column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table

I'm trying to format data like this for a report I nee to write:
(different amount of rows per column)
Per City, the list of suburbs must show, and then a list of vehicles that they have in e.g. Austin.

```
    City    Suburbs   Vehicles
  1 Austin  Bastrop   Ford
  2         Hutto     Mazda
  3         Lakeway   Mercedes
  4         Luling  
  5         ShadyHollow 
  6         WellsBranch 
  7         BrushyCreek 
  8         Elgin   
  9         Jollyville  

  10  Dallas    Belmont         BMW
  11            Eastwood        Ford
  12            GreenlandHills  
  13            LakeParkEstates 
  14            Lochwood
```

This is the source data

```
declare @Test0 table(city nvarchar(10), [state] varchar(30))
   insert into @Test0 values ('Austin',  'Texas')
   insert into @Test0 values ('Dallas',  'Texas')

 declare   @Test1 table (city nvarchar(10), suburb nvarchar(30) ) 
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'Bastrop')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'Hutto')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'Lakeway')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'Luling')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'ShadyHollow')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'WellsBranch')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'BrushyCreek')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'Elgin')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Austin',  'Jollyville')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Dallas',  'Belmont')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Dallas',  'Eastwood' )
    insert into @Test1 values ('Dallas',  'GreenlandHills')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Dallas',  'LakeParkEstates')
    insert into @Test1 values ('Dallas',  'Lochwood')

  declare @Test2 table(city nvarchar(10), vehicle nvarchar(30))
     insert into @Test2 values ('Austin',  'Ford')
     insert into @Test2 values ('Austin',  'Mazda')
     insert into @Test2 values ('Austin',  'Mercedes-Benz')
     insert into @Test2 values ('Dallas',  'BMW')
     insert into @Test2 values ('Dallas',  'Ford' )



 select * from @Test0 t0 join @Test1 t1 on t0.city = t1.city
 join @Test2 t2 on t0.city = t2.city
```

Where do I start please? Is pivot the answer? Am I even pivoting?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select City, 
 (
 select suburb + ' ' from @test1 where city=a.city for xml path(''),
 type).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'
 ),
 (
 select vehicle+ ' ' from @test2 where city=a.city for xml path(''),
 type).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'
 ) 
 from @test0 a
```

Comment: Hi this is almost working thanks, is it possible to create new rows  as it currently creates 2 rows :City (No column name) (No column name)
Austin BastropHuttoLakewayLulingShadyHollowWellsBranchBrushyCreekElginJollyville Ford Mazda Mercedes-Benz 
Dallas BelmontEastwoodGreenlandHillsLakeParkEstatesLochwood BMW Ford

Comment: not sure what you mean by creating new rows, can you specify that?

Comment: OK i've added row numbers to the original question now, thank you